# Usage of "as" in a sentence

Tags: grammar

"A local bowling league 'established its handicap for bowlers who have an average of 200 or **less as** 75% of the difference between 200 and the bowler's average score?."----from a question in ACT math.

I do not understand what does it mean to say "or less as 75% of the difference", especially feeling "as" here is very strange. And I even fail to identify the part of speech of "as".

Answer (score 1):

The "as" doesn't belong to the "or less", it follows on from "established its handicap". Let me put some brackets in to help identify the parts of the sentence:

"[A local bowling league established its handicap] [for bowlers who have an average of 200 or less] [as 75% of the difference between 200 and the bowler's average score.]"

Which could be rephrased as:

"For bowlers who have an average of 200 or less, a local bowling league established its handicap as 75% of the difference between 200 and the bowler's average score."

Answer (score 0):

*Less* and *as* are not part of the same constituent in this sentence.

*As* is a preposition heading prepositional phrase *as 75% of...*. It contains a predicative complement *75% of...*

It means that *the handicap for bowlers who have an average of 200 or less* is now *75% of the difference between 200 and the bowler's average score* for this local bowling league.

The sentence could be re-arranged in this way:

> A local bowling league established its handicap as 75% of the
>   difference between 200 and the bowler's average score for bowlers who
>   have an average of 200 or less.

Another way of understanding *as* in this context is *to be*